# Python 3, tkinter, buttons

Tags: button, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to move my button in tkinter, i am making game chess and want to click first time on figure and on second click move this, someone know how does it possible ?

Thx !

Comment: Don't use buttons for figures. Instead, use a canvas and calculate which figure was clicked from the click coordinates. Or if you insist on using buttons, change the assignment of buttons to figures.

Comment: Hm... But i use canvas for table and figure, and create button from canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use buttons for this although it is uncommon. Make pure black/white frames for the empty squares. Manage the alias of the buttons of the figures individually (maybe you should manage white/black background in the figure subclasses). Use a 8x8 grid in a frame and make them show/hide using `grid()` and `grid_remove()` / `grid_forget()`.

You can find a nice reference [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) and [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).